# Correct method of DI with regards to route.thephpleague.com

Tags: dependency-injection, slim, thephpleague

I received feedback on code of mine that said I was using Dependency Injection incorrectly:

> You are using the DI, but you are not utilizing it anywhere except for
>   `Request` and `Response`. The following 10 lines will always
>   instantiate the objects, even though you are never using them.

On these lines I have things like

```
$router->map('GET', '/tokens/{id}', [new APIController($server, $tokenRepository, $logger), 'get']);
$router->map('GET', '/tokens', [new APIController($server, $tokenRepository, $logger), 'list']);
....
$response = $router->dispatch($container->get('request'));
```

Which according to the [documentation](https://route.thephpleague.com/4.x/controllers/), seems to be the correct way to do it. Bootstrap.php:

```
$container  = new Container;
$logger = new Logger('book');

$tokenRepository = new RedisTokenRepository($predis, $logger);

$container->add(Logger::class);
$container->add(Server::class);
$container->add(TokenController::class)->addArguments([Server::class, $logger]);
$container->add(APIController::class)->addArguments([Server::class, $tokenRepository, $logger]);

$strategy = (new ApplicationStrategy)->setContainer($container);
$router   = (new Router)->setStrategy($strategy);

$router->map('GET', '/', [new Acme\APIController, 'someMethod']);
```

Controller

```
class APIController
{
    private $server;
    private $tokenRepository;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Server $server,
        TokenRepositoryInterface $tokenRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->tokenRepository = $tokenRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The feedback most likely refers to you actually instantiating the Classes for the route definitions; and you are manually passing the dependencies to them.

```
$router->map('GET', '/tokens/{id}', [new APIController($server, $tokenRepository, $logger), 'get']);
```

note the `new` keyword

with this approach, while parsing the file the system will create the instances of the `APIController`s - yes several.

you should either use

```
$router->map('GET', '/', [APIController::class, 'get']);
```

or

```
$router->map('GET', '/', 'APIController::get');
```

this way the router will only instantiate them once they are needed

It seems your method needs `$server, $tokenRepository, $logger`,
define them as the [documentation describes](https://route.thephpleague.com/4.x/dependency-injection/) them on the `Controller class`

Comment: When I do either of the ways above or in the documentation I linked to, I get 1. "Too few arguments to function Tokens\Controllers\APIController::__construct(), 0 passed in /server/http/vendor/league/route/src/Route.php on line 122 and exactly 3 expected" or 2. 'APIController' not found

Comment: I think you missing the DI definition for your controller and maybe even the container; see the end of [this page](https://route.thephpleague.com/4.x/dependency-injection/)

Comment: I have done that, please see the edit above. Same errors occur.